# Integrated Security Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure-virtual-machine

We have just set up our first virtual machine on windows azure and I've never had problems like this with something so simple.  Our connection string is very basic:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=<DBNAME>;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

But we are getting this error:

```
Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\<HOSTNAME>$'
```

I don't understand where the workgroup or the $ is coming from and I can't see to add that user to Sql Server.  Obviously I am missing something really obvious and would appreciate any help someone can offer.

We created a Server 2012 R2 DataCenter edition with Sql Server 2012

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misread and just noticed you had a virtual machine instead of the azure db. The workgroup is likely assumed unless you have joined the VM to an existing domain in the environment. Have you tried creating a standard SQL account with necessary db permissions?

Integrated security is not supported in azure databases.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394108.aspx

Comment: I have created an account in Sql Server and I can connect from the application using the User Id and Password in the connection string but we normally use integrated security on our other servers (not in azure) which works fine.  We want to migrate our websites into azure virtual machines.  We use Octopus Deploy and I'd rather not have to go through adding user IDs and passwords to all the config replacements values but nothing I try can get integrated security working. I understand the azure sql databases don't support this but this is a full sql server install, surely it works there?

Comment: We have used integrated security in azure vms with sql server, so definitely possible.  The only difference we have had is we setup a site to site vpn toor production environment so we join the vm to a domain.  Our developers are the only ones using integrated security,  so we add their domain security group with appropriate permissions on the box,  and have had no issues.  You may also check how your are accessing the sql connection.  Sounds like an iis app,  so if so, check what user the app pool runs as and make sure that user account has access to your db.

Comment: We just went with a sql account instead of integrated security.